# How to add content to File in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        decode E = new decode();
        String input = "apple";
       encode output  = E.compute(input);
        System.out.println("input decoded :" +E.d_decode(output))
}
```

Hi, I want the **output** to be printed in a file instead of printing it to the console. How do I do that? And I want the file to be created at the run time.I mean I am not adding the output to the already created file

Please be patient as I am new to java

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Comment: Do you mean you want to write the content to file or you want to use a logger to write it to a log file?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) which is available from Java 7 to write contents to a file in runtime. The file will be created if you give a correct path also you can set the preferred encoding.

**JAVA 7+**

*Edited after suggestion of @Ivan*

You may use [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) etc. there are many ways. I am sharing an example with [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
String encodedString = "some higly secret text";
Path filePath = Paths.get("file.txt");
try {
    Files.write(filePath, encodedString, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("unable to write to file, reason"+e.getMessage());
}
```

> To write multiple lines

```
List<String> linesToWrite = new ArrayList<>();
linesToWrite.add("encodedString 1");
linesToWrite.add("encodedString 2");
linesToWrite.add("encodedString 3");
Path filePath = Paths.get("file.txt");
try {
    Files.write(filePath, linesToWrite, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("unable to write to file, reason"+e.getMessage());
}
```

There are a million other ways but I think it would be good to start with because of its simplicity.

**Before Java 7**

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
String encodedString = "some higly secret 
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(encodedString);
    // to write multiple: writer.println("new line")
} catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: It might not be obvious from your answer but option with `PrintWriter` will also work in Java 7 and 8.